# Android app is working only when I installed it from Android Studio But not when I install the APK directly on other phones

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to save a string using sharedprefernces. Everything worked fine when I used my phone as the emulator. Android Studio installed the app on my phone and it is working as expected.

The problem is, I transferred the apk file to other phone using shareIt and it is not working on it. Toast is working but when I click save button, app closes saying unfortunately stopped working.

Then I installed the same project using Android Studio and it worked without any issues.

I tested on 3 devices and same problem on everything. Why it is not working when installed directly using APK.

Here is the code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package geekdashboard.learningtetsing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PROFILE_CHANGER_KEYWORDS";
    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "silent";
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void toastTesting(View view) {

        // Code for Toast
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Toast is Working :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Toast End
    }


    public void savingValue(View v) {
        // Reading value from name editField
        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        String enteredName = nameField.getText().toString();

        if (enteredName.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Empty Keyword Not Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                    "com.geekdashboard.learningtetsing", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putString(PREFS_KEY, enteredName).commit();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    enteredName + " has been saved to " + PREFS_NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void showValue(View sv) {

        SharedPreferences prefsread = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "com.geekdashboard.learningtetsing", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedValue = prefsread.getString(PREFS_KEY, null);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                savedValue + " is the last saved value in "+ PREFS_NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="geekdashboard.learningtetsing.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonString"
        android:onClick="toastTesting"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#212121"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/button" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonShared"
        android:background="@color/accent_material_light"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:onClick="savingValue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Enter Your Name Here"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/showValue"
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="showValue"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="geekdashboard.learningtetsing">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

showValue and saveValue methods are not working when apk file is installed manually.

Thank You

Comment: Please post the logcat error trace of crash.

Comment: Where can I get it? When I installed it from Android Studio it is working fine.

Comment: Install the app by sharing the apk, the way you are doing it. Just plug it with your machine and see the logs.

Comment: Here it is 
http://pastebin.com/MJvMryg0

Comment: Is this the full layout xml? Also, please post your manifest file.

Comment: Yes, it is the full layout file. I edited the post and added the code of manifest file. Please have a look.

Comment: I looked it at various places and seems like an issue with theme. Could you try using any different theme in manifest and also make sure layout file doesn't have any theme set on any of the elements.

Comment: No, not a theme issue. I modified the code a bit and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way using sharedPreferences and it worked. Here is the modified code.

```
package geekdashboard.learningtetsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PROFILE_CHANGER_KEYWORDS";
    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "silent";
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void toastTesting(View v) {

        // Code for Toast
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Toast is Working :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Toast End
    }


    public void savingValue(View view) {
        // Reading value from name editField
        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        String enteredName = nameField.getText().toString();

        if (enteredName.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Empty Keyword Not Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

           // Context context = getActivity();
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            //prefs.edit().putString(PREFS_KEY, enteredName).commit();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, enteredName);
            editor.commit();


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    enteredName + " has been saved to " + PREFS_NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void showValue(View sv) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       String defaultValue = "Silent";
        String savedValue = sharedPref.getString(PREFS_KEY, defaultValue);

        /* SharedPreferences prefsread = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "com.geekdashboard.learningtetsing", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedValue = prefsread.getString(PREFS_KEY, null); */
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                savedValue + " is the last saved value in "+ PREFS_NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ProGuard configuration error.

Comment: What does it mean? Can you help me to solve the error